# Python and the modulus operator with very large numbers

Tags: python, primes, modulus

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question - my search for `python` and `modulus` ran up to 8 pages of questions and that combined with my relatively little coding experience made it somewhat difficult for me to check thoroughly to see if there was anything extremely similar out there.

While trying to solve a [Project Euler](https://projecteuler.net) question, I wrote a function for testing whether or not a number was a prime number:

```
import math
def isprime(n):
    if n % 1 != 0:
        return(False)
    else:
        for j in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
            if n % j == 0:
                return(False)
            else:
                return(True)
        break
```

This works pretty well with small numbers, but with very large numbers that definitely *aren't* prime (e.g. I put in `isprime(1012321312412431434334545555)` and the function gives me a value of `True`). Why is this the case?

EDIT: as pointed out by roippi and confirmed by my further investigations, this function actually does not work for a lot of smaller odd composite numbers. I'm trying to figure out why that doesn't work for now.

Comment: Your function believes `15` is prime.  Investigate that, and you have your answer.

Comment: Your function also 'breaks' if I test 3 or 4.

Comment: Ah thanks for the feedback. My code writing skills are ... slightly questionable so that's helpful to know.

Comment: if you do `return(False)` in python, you'll be returning a tuple containing `False`, not false. Corrected that in an edit.

Comment: @zmo that's not true at all.  Also even if that were true, edits should not change fundamental parts of code that alter semantics.

Comment: oh, my bad. Though I corrected the wrong indentation, the first space and the missing column.

Comment: @Kevin: fixed it - I somehow missed the fact that I needed to add `1` to the second part of the `range` bit to account for the fact that it ends at `n-1` for `range(1,n)`. Still investigating the rest of this.

Comment: @roippi: yep, seems to be some problem with my code - it doesn't work for a lot of odd non-primes for some reason I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @zmo The tuple containing `False` would be `(False,)`.

Comment: @Maroon perhaps it helps to know that once you `return` something, your function is done executing.  Your `for` loop never checks anything other than if a number is divisible by 2.

Comment: @roippi That's true. I printed j to debug every loop and it stops at 2.

Comment: @alecb as I said: my bad ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is that the return is in the wrong place. Your code currently only loops through the 2, and any odd number is obviously not divisible by 2. So, it goes into the if n%j==0, returns True, and since a return breaks out of the loop, stops going. So, any odd number will return True.

Instead, try:

```
def isprime(n):
    if n % 1 != 0:
        return True
    else:
        for j in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n))):
            if n % j != 0:
                return False
        return True
```

I think that works.
EDIT: No, it actually doesn't. Here, I'll post a different prime checker:

```
def isprime(n):
    '''check if integer n is a prime'''
    n = abs(int(n))
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n == 2: 
        return True    
    if not n & 1: 
        return False
    for x in range(3, int(n**0.5)+1, 2):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all. The `n % 1` does nothing because every integer is divisible by 1. The else doesn't make sense either and it just returns completely wrong results

Comment: Sorree... but I just copied his code and tweaked it a bit. If you really want a different prime checker, I'll post one.

Comment: Using abs() is bad. Negative integers are not prime by definition, so it should return False for those.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `n % 1 == 0` will always return true for integers, because this tests if n is divisible by 1. So this is a bit of a nonsical test. If you want to check for odd/even numbers, use `n % 2`.

It does check for decimals, but in that case I think it's better to throw an error.

A better algorithm to test for prime is something like this:

```
def isPrime(n):
    if n < 2:
        return False
    if n < 4:
        return True
    for x in range(2,ceil(sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if (n % x == 0):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: Oh, I wanted to check for decimals, though in retrospect it was kinda pointless since given that I'm inputting values myself, that shouldn't happen.

Comment: Not sure why you accepted the other answer. I'm not sure what it does, but it doesn't check for primes. Edited a bit about checking for decimals.

Comment: @popvitsj: I was probably hastier than I normally am in accepting answers, and the initial code seemed to work for me / explain in a ways why things work.